# Can anyone tell me where I can get a replacement thermostat(see PicS)

Tags: wiring, thermostat, fireplace, replacement

Just wondering if anyone can tell me where to get a replacement thermostat for the one in the pics. I put it in in 2010 and I'll be darned if I can find a replacement. It's a three wire RWG Thanks Thx[image]

Comment: What make and model is your fireplace?

Comment: What make and model is _the thermostat_?